# character truncation from string in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-recognition

I am doing the number extraction of plate in MATLAB. There are two kinds of number plate, one is with pwd symbol other one without it. I am getting 8 characters are output. My expected output are 6 characters if there is no pwd symbol in the output else its 7 from right to left. My sample output is 14184940 and 0PwDsymbol012345. I am using 'strfind' to check if pwddymbol is presented in the output.How can i truncate the output character? This code is for number recognition.

```
function strPlate = Recognition(Objects,ImgChar)
% clc;
% clear all;
global templates;
load templates;
strPlate=[];
    I=imread('images.jpg');
%     I=imread('2222.jpg');
    figure,imshow(I);
    [ImgPlate] = LocationPlate(I);
    [Objects,ImgChar]=Segmentation(ImgPlate);
    num_letras=size(templates,2);
    for i=1:Objects
    char=ImgChar(:,:,i);
    char=imresize(char,[100 100]);
    char = medfilt2(char,[3 3]);
    figure,imshow(char);title('filtered')
    % use adaptive histogram equalisation
    char = adapthisteq(char);
       % contrast stretching
    char = imadjust(char);
    se=strel('disk',1); % Structural element (disk of radius 1) for morphological processing.
chari=imdilate(char,se); % Dilating the gray image with the structural element.
% figure,imshow(chari);
% title('chari')
chare=imerode(char,se); % Eroding the gray image with structural element.
gdiff=mat2gray(chare); % Converting the class to double.
gdiff=conv2(gdiff,[1 1;1 1]); 
gdiff=imadjust(gdiff,[0.5 0.7],[0 1],0.1); % Intensity scaling between the range 0 to 1.
H=bwmorph(gdiff,'thin',1);
final=imresize(H,[100,100]);
letter=read_letter(final,num_letras);
strPlate=[strPlate letter ];
end
locations = strfind(strPlate, 'PwDsymbol');
fid = fopen('noPlate.txt', 'wt'); 
if isempty(locations)
fprintf(fid,'%s\n','number plate has no PwD symbol hence violation.\n');
else
fprintf(fid,'%s\n','number plate has PwD symbol hence no violation.\n'); 
end
fclose(fid);                     
winopen('noPlate.txt')
```

Comment: Which part are you trying to truncate? e.g. when you get 14184940 is it supposed to be 1418494 or 4184940 or...???

Comment: Can you add dataset sample?

Comment: Why is the image processing portion of your code relevant if your problem is in string processing? Provide a [mcve] with input strings with and without the PwD symbol, your desired output for those strings, your code so far and exactly why it doesn't meet your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify whether the truncation must happen at the beginning or at the end of your strings. Anyway, this is a marginal problem once you know how to perform a truncation.

Let's suppose you want to remove the first character from a string (to be exact, a character array):

```
s = '0PwDsymbol012345';
s = s(2:end); % Output: 'PwDsymbol012345'
```

Let's suppose you want to remove the last two characters from a character array instead:

```
s = '14184940';
s = s(1:end-2); % Output: '141849'
```

That's all. Now you are free to tweak your string truncation process according to your needs. A sanity check on the string length is recommented anyway, before proceeding with the truncation, so your output will not be messed out... even if a truncation overflow produces an empty string:

```
s = '12345';
s = s(1:end-10); % Output: ''
```